# Deleting the objects in different entities (Core Data)

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a database (coredata) with 2 entities (with no relationships)... Inserting and fetching works well in my case.. But deleting part is troubling me a lot.. The object in one entity got deleted but others are nt..

Here is my code:

```
    -(void)deleteObject:(NSString *)entityDescription //entityDescription get entity name 
       {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
                        NSError *errors;
                        NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errors];
                        NSManagedObject *managedObject=[finalArray objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];
                        for (int i=0;i<[items count];i++)
                        {
                            if ([managedObject isEqual:[items objectAtIndex:i]])
                            {
                                 [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
                            }
                        }

                            NSLog(@"%@ object deleted", entityDescription);

                         NSNotificationCenter *nc1=[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
                        [nc1 addObserver:self selector:@selector(deleteCheck:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;
                if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
                {
                    NSLog(@"error occured during save = %@", error);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"deletion was succesful");
                }
```

This my code I follow the same method for deleting the objects from other entities...The entitydescription gets the different entity name from another method... Itz working well for one entity and not for another...But I'm getting the managedObjectContext deletion successful message(bt not deleted frm DB).. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you might do to narrow it down:

```
  NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errors];
  // Add this to see that you are returning items from your fetch
  NSLog(@"%i objects returned in items array",items.count);
  NSManagedObject *managedObject=[finalArray objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];
  // Add this to see what your fetch is returning
  NSLog(@"Fetch returned %@", managedObject);
  for (int i=0;i<[items count];i++)
  {
     // Add this to see for yourself if it is equal to managedObject
     NSLog(@"Testing: %@",[items objectAtIndex:i]);
     if ([managedObject isEqual:[items objectAtIndex:i]])
     {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        // Move this to here so you know each time an object is deleted
        NSLog(@"%@ object deleted", entityDescription);
     }
   }
```

I suspect that you want to test a property of the object, not that the objects are equal. You were reporting "object deleted" when loop finished regardless of whether or not you had deleted anything. If you meant to test a property of the managed object change your test to:

```
If ([managedObject.propertyToTest isEqual:[items objectAtIndex:i]])
```

Or a property of each item:

```
If ([managedObject isEqual:[items objectAtIndex:i].propertyToTest])
```

Comment: Well thanks for ur response..... I'm nt reporting objected deleted at the end of the loop... I'm checking the status of managedObjectContext there i print the report whether its deleting or it gets error...

Comment: I am referring to your NSLog at the end of the For loop. My example moves it up into conditional statement inside the loop so that you know if anything is being deleted. Where you had it, it was just telling you that your loop has completed and not whether or not anything was deleted.